# was the xml empty after XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

so yesterday, i used the following code, and it was able to produce something:

```
<xsl:variable name="radiofields" select="AllYourBase/*[name() != 'Australia']"/>
<Table style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">    
    <xsl:for-each select="$radiofields">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>                      
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[name() != 'ReadOnly']"/> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</Table>
```

and it was able to generate something through the XSLT processor.

right now, there is no output at all...could it be someone else changed or altered the xml? 
is there anyway to create a logger in my xsl file above to test if `radiofields` is empty, or at least print out its contents?

Comment: Can you plz provide an example of the input xml / html?

Comment: Could you share the XML file which you are processing with us?

Comment: yeah thats the problem...our 3rd party doesnt reveal the XML as it is highly confidential stocks andall :\

Comment: is there a way to create print statements in XSL? i would like to print out the contents of the xml